# duplicate stack trace detection in java

Tags: java, hash, duplicates, stack-trace

I am trying to find out a good hash function or utility code that can be used to check if a stack trace already exists.

So, far I am using a simple logic to compare 
first 2000 characters and another 2000 characters beginning from the caused by part if it exists.

This will do the job however, a more technical solution to do it would be desired.

Comment: How do you define a duplicate of stack trace? Is it duplicate array of (class.method.lineNumber)

Comment: Would converting the stack trace to a string and then use that string for comparison work for you?

Comment: well as this code has to run inside a mobile application so performance and memory both would be a concern. converting entire stack trace and comparing with another as string seems very expensive operation

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

initialize:

```
StackTraceElement[] previous = null;
    StackTraceElement[] current = null;
```

Assuming this code starts somewhere in main:

```
    StackTraceElement[] stackTrace = Thread.getCurrentThread().getStackTrace();
    if( previous == null )
    {
       previous = stackTrace;
    }
    else if( current == null )
    {
       current = stackTrace;
    }



    if ( Arrays.equals( current, previous ) )
    {
        duplicateStackTrace = true;
    }


    previous = current;
    current = null;
```

assuming the built-in equals() function of StackTraceElement works for you:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj==this)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof StackTraceElement))
            return false;
        StackTraceElement e = (StackTraceElement)obj;
        return e.declaringClass.equals(declaringClass) &&
            e.lineNumber == lineNumber &&
            Objects.equals(methodName, e.methodName) &&
            Objects.equals(fileName, e.fileName);
    }
```

Comment: this is good however for running the code inside a mobile application this looks like expensive operation. Especially when i will have a registry of stack traces to compare against

Comment: when you already have registry of stack traces which I think is nothing but a list of them, cannot you use Arrays.equals()? may be I am missing something

Answer (score 0):

I have used stack trace hashing in the past to "bucket" exceptions so that I can more easily see which errors are most frequent. The simplest, most straightforward way to implement as stack trace hash would be something like this:

```
public static int computeStackTraceHash(StackTraceElement[] trace) {
  return Arrays.hashCode(trace);
}
```

However, it's worth noting that the implementation of `StackTraceElement.hashCode()` introduces a couple of wrinkles that you may wish to consider. The hash code for a `StackTraceElement` is computed by XORing the following together:

- `fileName.hashCode()`
- `lineNumber`
- `declaringClass.hashCode()`
- `methodName.hashCode()`

(If the file name, declaring class or method name is unknown, the corresponding property will be null, and 0 is used instead of the hash for computation.)

If dynamically-generated classes are part of your stack trace (common with libraries like Spring), the name of some classes in the trace may be random, which will ruin your hash. Thus, you may wish to detect these classes in the trace and omit them. You may also wish to omit line numbers from the hash computation, which will make your "buckets" more tolerant of minor changes in your code. There could be other things you will need to consider for your personal scenario. So this can change your computation to look something like this:

```
public static int computeStackTraceHash(StackTraceElement[] trace) {
  List<Object> components = new ArrayList<>();

  for (StackTraceElement el : trace) {
    if (includeElement(el)) { // decide whether we're including this element
      components.add(el.getClassName());
      components.add(el.getMethodName());
    }
  }

  return components.hashCode();
}
```